# Not scraping whole html and table

Tags: python, html, database, escaping, data-science

I am trying to extract the table from this website  When I am scraping, it is not giving the full html script. also the table tag has no class or id in it. Can anyone suggest how to extract? [https://www.jaivikkheti.in/inputsupplier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irOrv.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/irOrv.jpg)
[url]: https://www.jaivikkheti.in/inputsupplier

Code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = url ="https://www.jaivikkheti.in/inputsupplier"
page = requests.get(URL)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, "html.parser")
  
# Reading the file and storing in a variable
contents = HTMLFileToBeOpened.read()
  
# Creating a BeautifulSoup object and
# specifying the parser 
beautifulSoupText = BeautifulSoup(contents, 'lxml')
  
  
# Using the prettify method to modify the code
#  Prettify() function in BeautifulSoup helps
# to view about the tag nature and their nesting
print(soup.body.prettify())
```

I see the data is inside some java file. because of that it is not able to extract.

Comment: please no images and add some code with description where you get stack

Comment: what did you try? Where is your code? Show it as text (not image) in question.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Selenium library in Python to access them.

Here is an example how you can do it, before you run the script below make sure that you have installed **selenium** and **numpy** using pip.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import numpy as np
import os

os.environ['MOZ_HEADLESS'] = '1'
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.jaivikkheti.in/inputsupplier")

# this line returns the table header tags in the HTML format
header_html = driver.find_elements(
    By.TAG_NAME, "th")

# this list comprehension parses the table header tags to get the text content
header_text = [item.text for item in header_html]

# this line returns the table body tags in the HTML format
body_html = driver.find_elements(
    By.TAG_NAME, "td")

"""
This list comprehension parses the table body tags to get the text content
It also separates them in two dimensional list each list containing a row
I'm using numpy to reshape them into 2D list
    reshape(int(len(body_html)/len(header_text)), len(header_text))
        int(len(body_html)/len(header_text) --> this is the number of rows in the table
        len(header_text) --> number of columns in the table
"""

body_text = np.array([item.text for item in body_html]).reshape(
    int(len(body_html)/len(header_text)), len(header_text))

print(header_text)
print(body_text)
```

Comment: This also is giving an. empty array.

Comment: You probably don't have a firefox driver installed - it's different from the browser itself. You can download the driver from https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases go to assets section then download the one corresponding to your operating system. Then run the code again, it should work if you have selenium, os, and the driver installed. Cheers!

Comment: Will chromedriver work? I am using Mac

Comment: Yes but you would need to change webdriver.Firefox() to webdriver.Chrome(). Make sure it's installed as Chrome driver is different from the Chrome browser.

Answer (score 0):

It's not giving you the full html because the table is rendered using javascript so you have to wait for the page to fully load.

You can use `selenium` if you know how to use it

Or

You can send a request through an Api that supports Javascript rendering like:

https://www.scraperapi.com/

Comment: This api didn't give the required output